# changing background image with jquery in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I'm using jQuery to change specific elements background-image in yii2.I got it working when i set background-image in css:

```
.farhangiAddi{
background-image : url('../axha/bakhshha/farhangi/F_icon01.png'),url('../axha/bakhshha/backgrand01.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
background-size: contain,contain;
height: 130px;
}
```

but when i change the image with jQuery nothing happened.in my view file:

```
<?php $this->registerJs("$('.farhangiAddi').mouseover(function(){
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(". url::to('@web/fajr/axha/bakhshha/farhangi/F_icon03.png')."');
});",view::POS_HEAD)?>
```

I think the problem is image inline addressing.
Thanks for any advice

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#container').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', "url('http://img.autobytel.com/car-reviews/autobytel/11694-good-looking-sports-cars/2016-Ford-Mustang-GT-burnout-red-tire-smoke.jpg')");
});

$('#container').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', "url('http://cdn3.droom.in/photos/images/drm/super-cars.png')");
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7ssttb5/1/)

Comment: I'm not using img tag. this is div background-image